# Difference between 'related_name' and 'related_query_name' attributes in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Can you explain the difference between `related_name` and `related_query_name` attributes for the Field object in Django ? When I use them, How to use them? Thanks!

Answer (score 107, accepted):

`related_name` will be the attribute of the related object that allows you to go 'backwards' to the model with the foreign key on it. For example, if `ModelA` has a field like: `model_b = ForeignKeyField(ModelB, related_name='model_as')`, this would enable you to access the `ModelA` instances that are related to your `ModelB` instance by going `model_b_instance.model_as.all()`. Note that this is generally written with a plural for a Foreign Key, because a foreign key is a one to many relationship, and the many side of that equation is the model with the Foreign Key field declared on it.

The further explanation linked to in the docs is helpful. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

`related_query_name` is for use in Django querysets. It allows you to filter on the reverse relationship of a foreign key related field. To continue our example - having a field on `Model A` like:
`model_b = ForeignKeyField(ModelB, related_query_name='model_a')` would enable you to use `model_a` as a lookup parameter in a queryset, like: `ModelB.objects.filter(model_a=whatever)`. It is more common to use a singular form for the `related_query_name`. As the docs say, it isn't necessary to specify both (or either of) `related_name` and `related_query_name`. Django has sensible defaults.

Comment: and `related_query_name defaults to the value of related_name or default_related_name if set, otherwise it defaults to the name of the model`

Comment: It seems there isn't big distinction between `related_name` & `related_query_name` since I can use an `related_name` in query like `ModelB.objects.filter(model_a=whatever)`. Untill now I didn't knew about `related_query_name` and still most of required cases used to get covered.

Comment: @JayVasant there is a distinction, and it's clearly defined. What you are seeing is the behaviour explained in the comment by @Windsooon: `related_query_name` defaults to the value of `related_name`.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Musician(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Here foreign key forward relation is Album to musician and backward relation is musician to album. This means one album instance can have relation with only one musician instance(forward relation), and one musician instance can relate to  multiple album instance(backward).
Forward query will be like this

```
Album_instance.artist
```

note here forward query done by Album_instance followed by artist(field name). and backward would be

```
Musician_instance.album_set.all()
```

here for backward query modelname_set is used .

now if you specifies the related_name like 
    `artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='back')`

then backward query syntax will be change modelname_set(artist.set) will be replace by back. 
now backward query

```
Musician_instance.back.all()
```

If you’d prefer Django not to create a backwards relation, set related_name to '+' or end it with '+'.

and related_query_name to use for the reverse filter name from the target model