# How to filter for a ManytoManyField with through in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, many-to-many, django-queryset

Trying to filter through all protocol data sources with their specific datasources in Protocol.

Tried to use this: ProtocolDataSource.objects.filter(protocol__data_sources=..., protocol__data_sources=...) but obviously this comes up with an error. The dots are the name of the data source.

Comment: Hi, please also include what you code tried, along with error message. This can help to solve your question quickly.

Answer (score 1):

To make your `related_query_name` more predictable, I suggest to add parameter `related_query_name` in your `ManytoManyField`

```
class Protocol(BaseWithImmutableKey):

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, unique=True, verbose_name='Protocol Name')

    # add related_query_name
    data_sources = models.ManyToManyField(
        DataSource, through='ProtocolDataSource', related_query_name='protocols')


# now you can reference reversely using protocols
DataSource.objects.filter(protocols__name=...)
```

You can read more here [what is related_name and related_query_name in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60119027/what-is-related-name-and-related-query-name-in-django)

Comment: Oh ok thanks for the response. Related query makes it easier to run the query. Question though, if i were to do a filter on ProtocolDataSource, but for data_sources objects what would the filter look like? Or even on users objects in Protocol. Still confused on the through portion and how it affects the filter.