# How to set all available values of one model to another model in django?

Tags: python, django

I have following code

```
class Version(models.Model):
      version = CharFeild
      version_url = UrlField

class MyModel(models.Model):
       name = CharFeild
       default_version = OnetoOneField(Version)
       available_versions = ForeignKeyField(Version)
```

i am getting stuck at when selecting available version i am only able to pick one, where i want to select all available or all the ones i require.

Comment: Use a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) instead of a `ForeignKeyField`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ForeignKeyField` refers to one `Version` from `MyModel`

You are misunderstanding the purpose of foreign keys. Your `MyModel` needs to be parent to all `Version`, that are used as `available_versions`, so that means You have to have one parent from child model, so your parent will have multiple childs and children will have only one parent. That means you have to use `ForeignKeyField` inside `Versions`

```
class Version(models.Model):
      version = CharFeild
      version_url = UrlField
      model = ForeignKey('MyModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='available_versions', null=True, blank=True)

class MyModel(models.Model):
       name = CharFeild
       default_version = OnetoOneField(Version, related_name='default_model')
```

I am not sure that there won't be any `related_names` collision (as it's a bit quirky), but I think you get the point

Comment: is there a way to get all available versions while making a query to My Model and return it in response

Comment: That will be `MyModel.available_versions.all()` I guess

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ForeignKey.related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), as Django documentation says will help you

you can use it like this

```
class Version(models.Model):
    version = CharFeild
    version_url = UrlField

class MyModel(models.Model):
     name = CharFeild
     default_version = OnetoOneField(Version)
     available_versions = ForeignKeyField(Version, related_name='model')
```

And you can use it like that

```
version = Version.objects.get(version="1.1.0")
models = version.model.all()
```

Also [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60119027/what-is-related-name-and-related-query-name-in-django)